# How to serialize a polars dataframe type in a pydantic v2 basemodel?

Tags: pydantic, python-polars

I have a pydantic (v2) BaseModel that can take a polars DataFrame as one of its model fields. I wish to be able to serialize the dataframe. Preferably, I would be able to serialize AND de-serialize it, but I would be happy with just being able to serialize it.

The polars dataframe has a `df.write_json()` method. My thinking has been that I would take the json output from that method and read it back in via the python `json` library, so that it becomes a json-serializeable dict. Then I would somehow attach this "encoder" to the pydantic json method. For the deserialization process, I would use the `pl.read_json()` method to produce a dataframe.

[Unfortunately, in the pydantic documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/serialization/#custom-serializers), I can tell how to write a custom serializer for a [named *field*](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/functional_serializers/#pydantic.functional_serializers.field_serializer), but not for a given *type*.

There are some [docs on serializing subclasses](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/serialization/#serializing-subclasses) by introducing a `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` class method, but I would prefer to avoid this approach, since I would like to be able to use the polars classes directly.

Here is an example where currently, `Foo().model_dump_json()` results in a `PydanticSerializationError: Unable to serialize unknown type: <class 'polars.dataframe.frame.DataFrame'>` error.

```py
from typing import Any
from pydantic import BaseModel
import polars as pl
import json

df = pl.DataFrame({"foo":[1,2,3], "bar":[4,5,6]})
df.write_json() # this produces a json representation of my dataframe
# {"columns":[{"name":"foo","datatype":"Int64","bit_settings":"","values":[1,2,3]},{"name":"bar","datatype":"Int64","bit_settings":"","values":[4,5,6]}]}

# I could use pl.read_json() to read it back into a dataframe.

def json_serializable_dataframe(df: pl.DataFrame) -> dict[str, Any]:
    "Load serialized dataframe into a serializable dict."
    return json.loads(df.write_json())

class Foo(BaseModel, arbitrary_types_allowed=True):
    df: pl.DataFrame = pl.DataFrame({"foo":[1,2,3], "bar":[4,5,6]})


Foo().model_dump_json() # how to incorporate my json_serializable_dataframe encoder here?
```

Is there a way to give pydantic the ability to serialize a custom type?

Comment: There's this https://github.com/JakobGM/patito

Comment: In your example `df` is a field though, so can't you use `@field_serializer("df")` (or @model_serializer?) Also, for serialization - if you call `.lazy()` you can use https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.deserialize.html

Comment: Hahaha, @DeanMacGregor, I'm one of the coauthors of patito :) I'm looking at smooth ways of us supporting pydantic 2, in addition to another case of passing basemodels to a logger that exports to json in the cloud.

Comment: @jqurious that is correct, but I want to be able to support the generic case of passing basemodel fields of any name with a dataframe type. You could say that it was by coincidence that the `df` field is called `df`.

Comment: It may be that I should be asking this pydantic question for a generic non-serializable python class. I just chose polars because of my work with patito and the fact that it has a nice .write_json method.

Comment: Ah okay. `@model_serializer` gives you access to "self" which you could walk for frames. Not sure if that's a suitable approach.

Comment: @TomNorway ha. I'm a dirty no-typer so whenever I see somebody ask about typing or structure I just link to patito but don't really get into it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use [`@model_serializer`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/serialization/#custom-serializers) and manually look for DataFrames?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel, arbitrary_types_allowed=True):
    a: pl.DataFrame = pl.DataFrame({"foo":[1], "bar":[2]})
    b: pl.DataFrame = pl.DataFrame({"baz":[3], "omg":[4]})

    @model_serializer
    def serialize(self):
        for name, obj in self.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(obj, pl.DataFrame):
                self.__dict__[name] = obj.lazy().serialize()
        return self.__dict__

Foo().model_dump_json()
```

```
'{"a":"{\\"DataFrameScan\\":{\\"df\\":{\\"columns\\":[{\\"name\\":\\"foo\\"...
```

note: Polars offers frame (de-)serialization via:

- [`LazyFrame.serialize`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.serialize.html)
- [`LazyFrame.deserialize`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.deserialize.html)